# Gaussian distribution with element-wise sigma in Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

To generate test data for my fitting algorithm I need to create an array of Gaussian noise, with its sigma specified element-wise. A pure-python implementation is as follows:

```
from numpy.random import normal
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        for k in range(100):
            image[i, j, k] += normal(0, sigmas[i, j, k])
```

This is meant to simulate a noisy image, where each pixel is a measurement 
value, with variance specified; for a reasonable test I need to generate noise coherent with variance (that I have given).

This implementation is too slow (I am working with big 3d arrays) so what I am looking for is a way to speed it up (most likely with vectorized lib methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `numpy.random.normal` can be arrays.
Pass your array `sigmas` as the second argument, e.g.

```
noise = normal(0, sigmas)
image += noise
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's strange it's not stated explicitly in the docs (they usually say `array-like`)

Comment: Or, indeed, `noisy_image = normal(image, sigmas)`

Comment: @RobertKern Ooh, I like that.